# Sort an Array based on Another Array with different values

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to sort an array based on another array with different values.
Consider the following:

Reference Array: `{"A","B","C"}`

Obtained Array1: `{"C","A","B"}`
Obtained Array2: `{"cc","aa","bb"}`
Obtained Array3: `{"123","asrd","sdhg"}`

values corresponding to

```
A -> aa and asrd
B -> bb and sdhg
C -> cc and 123
```

I want to sort my obtained array 1, 2 and 3 in the order specified by my reference array.

Expected Result:
Obtained Array after sorting: `{"A","B","C"}`
Obtained Array2 after sorting: `{"aa","bb","cc"}`
Obtained Array3 after sorting: `{"asrd","sdhg","123"}`

PS: The reference array elements order can be anything (`[A,B,C]` or `[C,B,A`] etc). Obtained arrays 2 and 3 should be sorted accordingly.

I know how to sort Obtained Array 1 in the order of my reference array. I tried a logic to sort obtained arrays 2 and 3 but the result i get is wrong

```
String[] referenceArray = new String[] { "A", "B", "C" };
String[] obtainedArray1 = new String[] { "C", "A", "B" };
String[] obtainedArray2 = new String[] { "cc", "aa", "bb" };
String[] obtainedArray3 = new String[] { "123", "asrd", "sdhg" };

final List<String> referenceArrayList= Arrays.asList(referenceArray);
ArrayList<String> obtainedArray1_List= new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(obtainedArray1));
ArrayList<String> obtainedArray2_List= new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(obtainedArray2));
ArrayList<String> obtainedArray3_List= new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(obtainedArray3));


// Sorting ObtainedArray1_List - This works Fine
Collections.sort(obtainedArray1_List, Comparator.comparing(s -> referenceArrayList.indexOf(s)));

//Sorting obtainedArray2_List - Not Working
Collections.sort(obtainedArray2_List, Comparator.comparing(s -> referenceArrayList.indexOf(obtainedArray1[obtainedArray2_List.indexOf(s)])));
```

The result of obtainedArray2_List  after sorting: `["aa","cc","bb"]`

> Expected Result is `["aa","bb","cc"]`

Comment: You're making yor own life complicated by not using OO design. Instead of having 3 parallel arrays, you should have a single array (or List, preferrably) of objects. Each object would have three properties (with the values "A", "aa", "asrd" for the first one), and you would then simply sort your list of objects by its reference property. Java is an OO language. Define classes, and use objects.

Answer (score 0):

As JB Nizet already said, you're making your life complicated. You have three separate arrays, while their contents are related. You're saying that `A`, `aa` and `asrd` belong together, as well as `B`, `bb` and `sdhg`, and `C`, `cc` and `123`.

These can be thought of three properties of a single object. That's the point of object-orientation. You should define a class which represents these three properties:

```
public class Holder {

    private String letter;
    private String lower;
    private String text;

    public Holder(String letter, String lower, String text) {
        this.letter = letter;
        this.lower = lower;
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getLetter() {
        return this.letter;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Holder(letter=%s, lower=%s, text=%s)",
            this.letter, this.lower, this.text);
    }
}
```

Your three arrays should never exist in the first place, but instead being an array or collection with `Holder` objects. For convenience, here is a transformation to a `List<Holder>`.

```
List<Holder> holders = IntStream.range(0, obtainedArray1.length)
    .mapToObj(i -> new Holder(obtainedArray1[i], obtainedArray2[i], obtainedArray3[i]))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Now you can simply sort collect a new, sorted list, instead of three separate sorted arrays.

```
List<String> referenceList = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C");
List<Holder> sorted = holders.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(t -> referenceList.indexOf(t.letter)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```